# Force 3G connection for iPhone?

Tags: mobile, iphone

I need to do some testing on 3G for a client and I have found no other way to do so without standing in the elevator. To avoid that, is there any way to force my iPhones to stay connected on 3G only? I have Mac Minis available that I could use as a proxy if that's an option. I've looked around a bit and found one idea that doesn't apply to my situation. It says go to Settings > Cellular > Voice & Data and change some settings, but it's not listed. It could be because I have AT&T on the devices, but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about software testing

Comment: Maybe better suited to the Ask Different board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings>General>Cellular and turn Enable LTE to Off [[Source]](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4482992).